# Регулярное выражение с флагом g

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Добрый день. Просьба помочь с регулярным выражением.
`<div>\s*<strong>\s*Ціна[\s[:alpha:]\,\.]*:\s*<\/strong>\s*(\d+[\s\d]*.\d*)\s*грн[\s[:alpha:]\,\.]*<\/div>` . Данное регулярное выражение находит совпадение с текстом, представленным ниже без флага g, с ним же не находит. Не могу найти причину.
Кусок документа, необходимый для совпадения с представленным регулярным выражением.
             `<div><strong>Ціна продажу:</strong> 2 743 300.00 ГРН</div>`

P.S. В документе имеется множество одинаковых тегов, т.е. `<div><strong>.*</strong></div>` но с различным содержимым.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby не поддерживает модификатор g, вместо этого для поиска используйте метод `scan`, а для замены `gsub`.

```
>> str = '<div><strong>Ціна продажу:</strong> 2 743 300.00 ГРН</div> <div><strong>Ціна продажу:</strong> 2 743 300.00 ГРН</div>'
>> str.scan /<div>\s*<strong>\s*Ціна[\s[:alpha:]\,\.]*:\s*<\/strong>\s*(\d+[\s\d]*.\d*)\s*грн[\s[:alpha:]\,\.]*<\/div>/i
=> [["2 743 300.00"], ["2 743 300.00"]]
```

Comment: я и использую gsub для замены, но при тестировании регулярного выражения через онлайн тестер с модификатором g не находит совпадения, а без него находит.

Comment: @Oleksii А что за онлайн тестер? Обычно рубисты проверяют код в irb. В нем я получил результаты выше, в нем же вы можете воспользоваться gsub. Какую цель преследуете, хотите заменить число на какое-то другое?

Comment: Я тестировал через этот https://regexr.com тестер, а так же через рельсовую консоль, через рельсовую консоль находит совпадения, а через тестер с модификатором g нет, а без него да, ну и так же в самом проекте тоже не находит.

Comment: Тогда не понятно в чем затруднение? g не поддерживается Ruby (в других диалектах регулярных выражениях, да, поддерижвается), gsub у вас работает.